# Windows Sublime Text, how to use Anaconda Python instead of default

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How do I go about setting sublime text to build with my anaconda python and not the default one? I have pyaudio installed in anaconda but when I build my page in sublime it says no module  of pyaudio found. I assume it is because it is building with the default python.

I have installed conda in the sublime package manager too and it says I am pointed to my anaconda python, still not working though.

Comment: If you can't find an answer, you could just execute your code from an anaconda terminal.

Comment: Yes, but I would much rather use my editor "sublime text" then use the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at the [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/basics.html) and tried it out, so this should work for you.

From within Sublime Text 3 navigate to 'Tools'>'Build System'>'New Build System'

Then, configure your build system file similar  to this (note our directories may differ):

```
{
  "cmd": ["C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

save it and name it something appropriate like 'anaconda_custom.sublime-build'

then open your python file and execute the Ctrl-Shift-B command to select the build option 'anaconda_custom' to build using the conda python.exe.

I haven't tested to see if this changes the default build for python but at least you have a pathway to execution with the conda python.exe.  There is probably a setting for that somewhere.

Also, if you haven't already tried it, I recommend [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the Kite extension installed for coding in Python.  I sometime use Sublime Text too but VSCode has become my new favourite.

I hope this helps.